# I am unable to start any QGIS version on windows 11

Tags: qgis, github, build, windows-11

It's been a few weeks now that on my Dell laptop, Windows 11 pro, I am unable to start any QGIS version.  Installations that were working, are now refusing to start.
I have removed and uninstalled the versions and the AppData local folders and added an explicit firewall open rule to allow all traffic but nothing makes it start.

The experience is that I see the splash screen, see the rolling stages and when it reaches the last one, "QGIS Ready!", nothing happens.  The only option is the windows popup "qgis-bin.exe not responding" with the option to wait (nothing happens) or kill it.

Has anyone experienced this?
Are there any logs that may give a clue as to why this is happening?

If I am to download and build a debug version from GitHub, how easy is it to debug through Visual Studio 2022 and see what it is waiting for?

Comment: I started the ProcMon and I see this stuck in a loop with:
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\{4e1cd581-868d-471d-b716-b5ac6a8fc200}\EnableDhcp

with different UUIDs all the time

Answer (score 2):

I experienced similar behavior (WIN 10, QGIS 3.34), in the end, I realised the firewall settings update helped (inbound/outbound rules).